# how to store images and text to sqlite database from async and show as gridview

Tags: android

how to

> store images and text

to sqlite database from async and show as gridview,
I'm using these two methods for

```
 public void insertData(String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("name",name);
    sqLiteDatabase.insert("pos",null,values);
    Log.v("insertion success",name);
}
public ArrayList fetchData()
{
    ArrayList<String>stringArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    String fetch_data="select * from pos";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(fetch_data, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do
        {
            stringArrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return stringArrayList;
}
```

1. how to insert image and retrieve

This is my insertion

```
 JSONObject jsonOBject = jsonData.getJSONObject(i);
                    service = jsonOBject.getString("service");
                    id=jsonOBject.getString("id");
                    icons = jsonOBject.getString("icon");

                    model = new ItemObject();
                    model.setContent(service);
                    model.setImageResource(icons);

                    arrayList.add(model);
                    database.insertData(service);
```

and set like this,

```
 database_arrayList=database.fetchData();
        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.activity_list_item,android.R.id.text1,database_arrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> Please help me

Comment: Store image path vs text in sqlite.

Comment: how to possible

Comment: Suppose you have an image in your sd card and its path is "storage/sdcard/image/joker.png" and the text you want to show is "Joker" so in the sqlite you can save as |joker|storage/sdcard/image/joker.png| while fetching it from db keep this mapping in model class and pass it to your adapter. In adapter use the image path to fetch the image and text filed to show text.

Comment: I think, this is not i look

Comment: please give some code samples